# Add an expression to calculate an attribute in the print composer with PyQGIS

Tags: attribute-table, print-composer, pyqgis-3, expression

In the print composer, it's possible to add an expression in the window "select attributes", in order to display an attribute that wasn't calculated in the attribute table of a layer, see an example below :

[image]

I would like to display 2 attributes containing area values, in hectares (unit of `'sup'` and `'supepnd'`) and in acres, without if possible calculating new fields.
I am using the following expression : `format_number(field*2.47105,2)`

Is it also possible using PyQGIS?

For now, I tried to copy the expression in the list of fields to display, but it's not working :

```
pdf_table = QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable.create(layout)
pdf_table.setVectorLayer(pdf)
pdf_fields = ['champ','sup','supepnd',format_number('sup'*2.47105,2),format_number('supepnd'*2.47105,2)]
pdf_table.setDisplayedFields(pdf_fields, True)
```

I thought maybe I should clone the columns, calculate the 2 new fields and set the content of the attribute table, but I don't understand how to call the columns values. I get `"AttributeError: 'QgsLayoutTableColumn' object has no attribute 'setContents'"`.

```
pdf = project.mapLayersByName('plan_de_ferme')[0]
champ_field = pdf.fields().indexFromName('champ')
sup_field = pdf.fields().indexFromName('sup')
supepend_field = pdf.fields().indexFromName('supepnd')
features = pdf.getFeatures()
champ = []
sup = []
supepend = []
nsup = []
nsupepend = []
length = 0
for feat in features :
    attr0 = feat.attributes()[champ_field]
    attr1 = feat.attributes()[sup_field]
    attr2 = feat.attributes()[supepend_field]
    champ.append((str(attr0)))
    sup.append(round(float(attr1),2))
    supepend.append(round(float(attr2),2))
    nsup.append(round(float(attr1*2.47105),2))
    nsupepend.append(round(float(attr2*2.47105),2))
    length += 1
tab = []

for i in range(length):
    tab.append([str(champ[i]), str(sup[i]), str(supepend[i]), str(nsup[i]), str(nsupepend[i])])

cols = pdf_table.columns()
new_cols = [col.clone() for col in cols]
for i, cloned_col in enumerate(new_cols):
    cloned_col.setContents(tab[i])
pdf_table.setColumns(new_cols)
#refresh layout
layout.refresh()
```

I also thought of adding the last two columns of the text table created previously next to my attribute table, but I am making an atlas and need the table to show only features visible on the map (changing for each page), and like a text table is not linked to a layer I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of copies of the existing columns in your table. You can then create additional `QgsLayoutTableColumn` objects, set their attribute and heading values and append them to the list of columns. Finally, use the `setColumns()` method on your table passing the updated column list and refresh the layout.

The code below should work for you.

```py
# your existing code
pdf_table = QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable.create(layout)
pdf_table.setVectorLayer(pdf)
pdf_fields = ['champ','sup','supepnd']
pdf_table.setDisplayedFields(pdf_fields, True)

#add this code...

# copy existing columns to a list
new_cols = [col.clone() for col in pdf_table.columns()]

#create and add additional columns
#don't forget double quotes around field names in expessions
add_col_1 = QgsLayoutTableColumn()
add_col_1.setAttribute('format_number("sup"*2.47105,2)')
add_col_1.setHeading('Sup.(ac)')
new_cols.append(add_col_1)

add_col_2 = QgsLayoutTableColumn()
add_col_2.setAttribute('format_number("supepnd"*2.47105,2)')
add_col_2.setHeading('Sup.ép(ac)')
new_cols.append(add_col_2)

pdf_table.setColumns(new_cols)

layout.refresh()
```

Results should be as below.

Example layout table before:

[image]

Columns in layer attribute table used in expressions:

[image]

Layout table after running code:

[image]